# PHP - return the words that show up the most inside a string

Tags: php, string

```
$string = 'I like banana, banana souffle, chocobanana and marshmellows.";
$arr = some_function($string); 
// $arr = ('banana'=>3,'I'=>1,'like'=>1....);
```

do you have an idea how to do this most efficiently?

Comment: You are not really looking at words if `chocobanana` creates a match for `banana`. Are sub words a requirement of what you are doing? If so, are they needing to split at proper suffixes/prefixes?

Comment: yes sir, they are, that's why i gave this example. For example, the word 'music' would match 'musician','music-industry','musical'...

Comment: How is "banana" counted 3 times when its part of "chocobanana"? Do you want to count partial matches of words that otherwise exist or what?

Comment: I want to treat every word like regex. I want to count all substrings inside the large string, and map them in array by occurrence.

Comment: Based on some dictionary or just any substring (e.g. 'a'=>11 in your example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = 'I like banana, banana souffle, chocobanana and marshmellows.';
$words = str_word_count($str, 1);
$freq = array();
foreach ($words as $w) {
  if (preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($w, '/') . '/', $str, $m)) {
    $freq[$w] = count($m[0]);
  }
}
print_r($freq);
```

Comment: Ha! I knew str_word_count was useful for this :)

Comment: I've checked it out, works well so far. do you have an idea how to sort the array by occurrence?

Comment: @Gal `asort` sorts an array and maintains index association

Comment: so i take it that want you want is,  if you have say, "altercation alternation" , then the word "alter" doesn't count right? "alter" is a sub-word within these 2 words "altercation" and "alteration".

Answer (score 2):

you can use [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

eg

```
$string = 'I like banana, banana souffle, chocobanana and marshmellows';
$s = preg_split("/[, ]+/",$string);
print_r(array_count_values($s));
```

note: this only count whole words. ie "banana" will be 2 , not 3 because chocobanana is not the same as banana. If you want to search and count for words within words, extra coding is necessary

Comment: so If I indeed want to count "chocobanana", i need to use explode and loop thru the string with preg_match_all basically? no other way around that?

Comment: its quite complicated. you need to know how to break up choco and banana. For example, you have "I" , but if you also have say, "Immediate", then how are you going to count "I" ? you need a way to separate out those words that have meaning ....

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('!\b\w+\b!', $string, $matches);
$arr = array_count_values($matches[0]);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to count partial words, you will need a wordlist with possible words. Then you split up the text in words based on space separation at first, loop through all words and **try to find the longest possible substring match against the wordlist**. This will of course be really, really slow if the wordlist is big, but maybe you can speed up the matching by using a [suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) of the word you are searching through.

If you don't find a matching substring, just count the whole word as one.

I hope you understand my idea. It's not that great, but it's the solution I can come up with for your requirements.